# Apply ifelse functions to a dataframe over a list

Tags: r, if-statement, lapply

I would like to make use of the `apply` functions to speed up the code.

I have extracted a list of cities in a list

```
targetcitylist :=> "London", "Hong Kong", "Dubai", "Paris"
```

and I have a separate huge data frame that looks something like this

```
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|      Period   |    City    | usercount |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|     Night     | Cardiff    |        35 |
|     Afternoon | Unknown    |        12 |
|     Afternoon | Norwich    |       111 |
|     Afternoon | Darlington |        13 |
|     Evening   | Bebington  |         6 |
|     Afternoon | Shrewsbury |        24 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

I want to do create a function that would loop through each row of the data frame and create a new variable, Cities, where unless they are in the list or else they would be classified as `Other`.

This is my slow attempt:

```
data$Cities <- ifelse(data$City == toString(targetcitylist[1]),toString(targetcitylist[1]), 
                            ifelse(data$City == toString(targetcitylist[2]),toString(targetcitylist[2]),
                                   ifelse(data$City == toString(targetcitylist[3]),toString(targetcitylist[3]),
                                          ifelse(data$City == toString(targetcitylist[4]),toString(targetcitylist[4]),
                                                 ifelse(data$City == toString(targetcitylist[5]),toString(targetcitylist[5]),
                                                        'Other')))))
```

And this is my try to speed up but failed attempt:

```
data$Cities = lapply(targetcitylist, function(x)ifelse(data$City==targetcitylist[x] , targetcitylist[x] ,'Other'))
```

Please could you simplify the syntax while optimizing the speed of the code?  the slow attempt really is slow.

Comment: Isn't this just `ifelse(data$City %in% targetcitylist, targetcitylist, "Other")`?

Comment: I think it is `ifelse(data$City %in% targetcitylist, data$City, "Other")`

Comment: @zx8754 Oh right :) /note to myself- test code before commenting.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg :) but unfortunately the in function doesn't give back exact result: as in +-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| UserDayPart | **City**   | usercount | **Cities** |
+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| Morning     | **Hong Kong** |       215 | **London**|
+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+

Comment: Yeah, see the fix in the second command, I've put `targetcitylist` instead of `data$City` by mistake.

Comment: Great thanks both @DavidArenburg and @ zx8754 it works! I was too keen on the apply functions  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below example:

```
#my list
targetcitylist <- c("London", "Hong Kong", "Dubai", "Paris")

#my data - note: only London should match my target list
data <- read.table(text="Period City usercount 
Night Cardiff 35 
Afternoon Unknown 12 
Afternoon London 111 
Afternoon Darlington 13 
Evening Bebington 6 
Afternoon Shrewsbury 24", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE) #no factors

#result
ifelse(data$City %in% targetcitylist, data$City, "Other")

#output
[1] "Other"  "Other"  "London" "Other"  "Other"  "Other"
```